# Text does not show properly in R plot

Tags: r, ubuntu, rstudio-server

My R was installed in a conda environment on Ubuntu 20.04.1 VM.

[image: The text in English does not show properly on a plot]

Comment: Please add part of your data and the important part of your code

Comment: It's just the plot(x , y) function. All the text in the plot the plot are like this regardless of data.

Comment: My guess is that you are missing a fonts package in your ubuntu machine.

Comment: Hi, do you know how can I add that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was searching for this problem when i found this thread. I too am using RStudio from Anaconda, on Debian 10.0 (buster).

Try

```
par(family  = "Arial")
```

or whichever font name before calling plot(). It worked for me.
**Update >** I still had problems with ggplot2 plots not displaying labels, like above. I tried the workaround of using **showtext()** instead of regular text rendering.

```
install.packages("showtext")
```

After it was installed,

```
library(showtext)
```

to load the library. Then simply call

```
showtext_auto()
```

followed by the **ggplot(.....) + ... + etc.** function and text was rendered alright within the  plot. I did not load specific fonts using **font_add()**. Maybe because previously '**Arial'** was loaded with **par()**